# How to add Plus Minus Toggle icon in my tree view

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a tree view which looks like: [image: tree image]

And my HTML code for this is:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="caret">Child</a>
  <ul class="nested">
    <li><a href="#" class="caret">Grand Child</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="caret">Grand Child</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="caret">Grand Child</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And I am add the icons using this CSS:

```
 .caret::after {
    content: "\002B";
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;

  } 
  
  .caret::before {
    content: "\2212";
    color: black;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px;
  }
```

And this is a javascript code to toggle this:

```
 var toggler = document.getElementsByClassName('caret');
      var i;

      for (i = 0; i < toggler.length; i++) {
        toggler[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
          this.parentElement.querySelector('.nested').classList.toggle('active');
          this.classList.toggle('caret-down');
          
        });
      }
```

I just want to toggle between plus and minus icon in this tree view any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `toggler`? And it is not quite clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: toggler is a variable where child class stored and I want to achieve toggle between plus minus icon

Comment: I don't understand what you meant by "toggle between plus and minus icon in this tree view". What  exactly is supposed to happen when you click the + or - buttons?

Comment: Okay when we click on plus icon then it will show it expanded child tree and plus sign change into minus so when we again click on minus sign it will change into earlier state